# can I config the maximum number for the entries in the jumplist

Tags: vim, vi

I just want to list the most recent motion locations (say, 10 or less) that I have just located when using the (:jumplist), the default value 100 is too big that I have to page down to the most recent ones.

Comment: I want to say no. I did a quick skim through the help and it seems the maximum is fixed at 100. I did not see any way to change it

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no command `:jumplist`, I guess you meant `:jumps`

There is no option for that setting. but what you could do is, do `:jumps` as usual, when the "long" list displayed, pressing `G` will bring you to the most recent ones.

Comment: You can clear the jump list with `:clearjumps` if it gets too long

Answer (score 0):

Here is a definition of `:Tail` (and the corresponding `:Head`) command, which allows you to limit the output of any Vim command to 10 lines:

```
:Tail jumps
(showing only the last 10 jumps)
```

#### Scriptlet

```
":[N]Head {cmd}     Show only the first 10 / [N] lines of {cmd}'s output.
":[N]Tail {cmd}     Show only the last 10 / [N] lines of {cmd}'s output.
function! s:CaptureCommand( command )
    redir => l:commandOutput
        silent! execute a:command
    redir END
    redraw  " This is necessary because of the :redir done earlier.
    return split(l:commandOutput, "\n")
endfunction
function! s:Head( count, command )
    let l:lines = s:CaptureCommand(a:command)
    for l:line in l:lines[0:(a:count ? a:count : 10)]
        echo l:line
    endfor
endfunction
function! s:Tail( count, command )
    let l:lines = s:CaptureCommand(a:command)
    for l:line in l:lines[-1 * min([(a:count ? a:count : 10), len(l:lines)]):-1]
        echo l:line
    endfor
endfunction
command! -range=0 -nargs=+ Head call <SID>Head(<count>, <q-args>)
command! -range=0 -nargs=+ Tail call <SID>Tail(<count>, <q-args>)
```

#### More ideas

You can also use this to define a custom `:Jumps` command:

```
command! -range=0 Jumps <count>Tail jumps
```

With the [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin, you can even override the built-in `:jumps` with it.